# Accessing a local variable of the main thread from another thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

The following is an example program from the book [Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013409266X) where the authors illustrate the usage of shared variables in multi-threaded programs:

```
#include "csapp.h"

#define N 2

void *thread(void *vargp);

char **ptr; /* Global variable */

int main()
{
    int i;
    pthread_t tid;
    char *msgs[N] = {
        "Hello from foo",
        "Hello from bar"
    };

    ptr = msgs;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        Pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread, (void *)i);
    Pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *thread(void *vargp)
{
    int myid = (int)vargp;
    static int cnt = 0;
    printf("[%d]: %s (cnt=%d)\n", myid, ptr[myid], ++cnt);
    return NULL;
}
```

As can be seen, both threads access the global variable `ptr` which points to the local variable `msgs` of the main thread which calls `pthread_exit`.

Now, according to the documentation of [pthread_exit](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_exit.html):

> After a thread has terminated, the result of access to local (auto) variables of the thread is undefined.

So, is the code above correct?

Is it legal to access a local variable of the main thread from another thread even though the main thread calls `pthread_exit`?

Comment: Why would `main` even call `pthread_exit`? it should rather call `pthread_join` and then your question will be resolved.

Comment: (1) It is the code from the book. (2) It is perfectly legal to call `pthread_exit` from the main thread and there are use-cases for this (for example, if the main thread just wants to spawn other detached threads without the need to wait for them to finish).

Comment: It is legal, yes. Also note, that it is basically the *value* of `i` which is passed. The thread is never dereferencing anything which is pointing to the `main` local object. So there is no problem that you are thinking about.

Comment: @EugeneSh. msgs is a local variable. Its first element is pointed to by the pointer ptr that is dereferenced ptr = msgs;

Comment: @EugeneSh. You are wrong. The threads evaluate `ptr[myid]` which access the `msgs` array which is a local variable of the `main` function.

Comment: Ah, you ate talking about `ptr`, I was looking at `i`. Sorry

Comment: This code should not compile for multiple reasons. If you're learning from a book that offers such code, please read the errata and, if that doesn't fix this, discard the book.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt If you're referring to the capital letters (e.g. `Pthread_create` instead of `pthread_create`), then it is OK, these are wrappers used in the book which check error conditions. In any case, the question is a general one and not tied to this specific example.

Comment: In C, you're not guaranteed to be able to access another thread's automatic storage at all, much less unsynchronized or after the end of its lifetime. The behavior is undefined.

Comment: What is the contents of `csapp.h`?  as it is, the posted code does not compile!

Comment: in the thread function: the best way to exit the function is: `pthread_exit( NULL );`

Comment: in the `main()` function: this: `pthread_exit(NULL);` should be: `for( i= 0; i<n; i++ )
        pthread_join(  tid, NULL );` followed by (for modern compilers) nothing.

Comment: for proper calls to `pthread_join()`  each call needs to use the TID of the appropriate thread.  Therefore, the `tid` needs to an array of `n` instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it legal to access a local variable of the main thread from another thread even though the main thread calls pthread_exit?

No. Once the main thread completes via `pthread_exit`, the lifetime of any local variable (i.e. *automatic storage duration*) ends. Any further access from another thread is **undefined behaviour**.

> So, is the code above correct?

No. The `msgs` array is a local variable whose lifetime ends after `pthread_exit` call. So any further access via `ptr` is undefined.

In general, it's valid to access local variables of one thread from another thread as long as the lifetime of those objects haven't ended. This is guaranteed by [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_404):

> [..] Anything whose address may be determined by a thread, including
> but not limited to static variables, storage obtained via malloc(),
> directly addressable storage obtained through implementation-defined
> functions, and automatic variables, are accessible to all threads in
> the same process.

Another thing to note is that if you have passed `msgs[0]` or `msgs[1]` to the threads, that would be valid. Because `msgs[0]` and `msgs[1]` point to string literals whose lifetime ends only when the program terminates (not just the thread which has a pointer to it).

Similarly, it's valid if you have allocated via `malloc` (or its friends) or any object with static storage duration and passed it to the thread function.

e.g.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>

void *thread_func(void *arg)
{
    char *str = p;
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t tid;
    char *p = "Hello";
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_func, p);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

This is totally fine because `p` points to a string literal which exists even after `main` returns via `pthread_exit`.

So the important distinction to note here is that whether the access to a variable in another thread is undefined depends on the **lifetime** of the said object, not just where a variable happens to be defined.